# How to automate curl POST for CSV file?

Tags: bash, csv, curl

I need to write a bash script that takes CSV file and iterates row by row, sending each row to `http://localhost:9999/myListener`.

In other words the script should execute this code for each N-th row of CSV file:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"col1":1,"col2":3,"col3":"value"}' http://localhost:9999/myListener
```

Comment: you are able to upload the whole file at once, if that suits

Comment: also post a few lines of your sample csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could translate csv to json line by line with awk:

```
cat foo.csv | \
awk -F',' '{printf("{\"col1\": %s, \"col2\": %s, \"col3\": \"%s\"}\n", $1, $2, $3)}' | \
while read s
do
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "$s" http://localhost:9999/myListener
done
```